# Recursive replacement function

Tags: javascript, html, regex, recursion, replace

QUESTION: How can I make this replacement function recursive?  Can it be infinitely recursive?  Please see fiddle and code samples.

> Edit: I added a fiddle here because it's got a lot of components to
> get the function going.  https://jsfiddle.net/tw9dq5av/2/

I have a replacement function I'm trying to get working.
Normally the function replaces %variable% with object.variable.

I want it to see an array in the data and recursively replace each item in the array with another call to template('arrayVariableName',arrayRowData).
so if obj.invoiceItems = [obj1,obj2,obj3] it would replace %invoiceItems% each with the content a call to template('invoiceItems',obj.invoiceItems.obj3)

The idea is that invoice items would repeat in a template for an invoice or questions would repeat in a questionnaire.  Any help is much appreciated.  Rendering them differently can be tricky in my app

```
function template(templateid, data) {
  return document.getElementById(templateid).innerHTML
    .replace(/%(\w*)%/g, function (m, key) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (Array.isArray(data[key])) {
          const itemTemplate = document.getElementById(key).innerHTML;
          return data[key].map((item) => {
            return itemTemplate.replace(/%(\w*)%/g, function (m, itemKey) {
              return item.hasOwnProperty(itemKey) ? item[itemKey] : "";
            });
          }).join('');
        } else {
          return data[key];
        }
      } else {
        return '';
      }
    });
}
```

sample template
I need it to work on data like this `{"invoiceName": "John Doe's Invoice", "invoiceItems":[{"name":"item 1","desc":"A Big Item"},{"name":"item 2","desc":"A small Item"}]}`

given having templates like this

```
<template id="%invoice%"><p>%invoiceName%</p><div>%invoiceItems%</template>
<template id="%invoiceItems"><p>%name%</p><em>%desc%</em></template>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but is there a question here?

Comment: first sentence: "I have a replacement function I'm trying to get working."

Comment: How is that a question? That is just a statement of what you are doing.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the final snippet that worked was one someone helped me with and took down their answer, while the function was working it wasn't rendering correctly so if anyone is having issues where the logic seems to work but you don't see it render this is related to DOM elements appearing on the screen before they're assigned in the DOM.  This results in issues pointing to elements.  Instead you can "render" the html to a varriable as a sort of virtual DOM and then insert it to the page.

```
 function template(templateid, data) {
  return document.getElementById(templateid).innerHTML
    .replace(/%(\w*)%/g, function (m, key) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (Array.isArray(data[key])) {
          const itemTemplate = document.getElementById(key).innerHTML;
          return data[key].map((item) => {
            console.log(template(key, item))
            return template(key, item);
          }).join('');
        } else {
          return data[key];
        }
      } else {
        return '';
      }
    });
}
```